# Creating a CloudFormation Conditional statement based on index of a paramater

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

What is the best approach for creating a CloudFormation Condition that generates a resource when an index exists in a list? The list length can vary from environment to environment, their will be up to 5 elements in the list.

Answer (score 2):

The only approach is through [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) or [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) as cloud formation does not allow you to query, iterate and search lists of dynamic sizes.

In both cases you have to develop a **lambda function** that will do the processing of your list.